# Inner Join, and Outer Join confusion

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to get data from one table, so I join it like so:

```
SELECT A.ACCT_NO
FROM   ACCOUNT AS A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER AS C
       ON A.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
WHERE  C.FIRST_NM = 'ADAM';
```

The problem right now is that I'm somewhat confused with regards to how the joins are functioning. If I change it to:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER AS C
```

Or even:

```
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS C
```

I get the same exact data! I'm following this chart right here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UKp7.png

Based on that, I assumed that only the RIGHT OUTER JOIN would work because it is only pulling the columns from CUSTOMER. However, that doesn't seem to be the case, as both outer joins work. In addition, I was shocked to see INNER JOIN work as well. Why is this? Or is it because I'm missing key concepts with regards to join in SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: You seemed to be very confused about how joins work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: When using outer joins, the limiting criteria on the table where you only want matching records MUST be placed on the join OR you have to use an or condition to handle NULL

Comment: You said, "Or is it because I'm missing key concepts with regards to join in SQL? " Yes this point.  You're missing a key concept on when limiting criteria is applied to the result set vs when the Cartesian form the join is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using outer joins, the limiting criteria on the table where you only want matching records MUST be placed on the join OR you have to use an or condition to handle NULL.  If you don't, you will get the same results as an INNER Join.  It has to do with when the join occurs vs when the where clause criteria is applied.  When the limiting criteria is on the join, it occurs before the join, in the where clause, after.  When in the where clause, the NULL values generated by the outer join are then excluded... by the where clause... making it look like an inner join.

Since I think you want all accounts but only customer information where first name is Adam, you need a left join but move the where clause criteria to the join.

**PREFERRED:**

```
SELECT A.ACCT_NO
FROM   ACCOUNT AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER AS C
       ON A.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
       AND C.FIRST_NM = 'ADAM';
```

OR

If you must

```
    SELECT A.ACCT_NO
    FROM   ACCOUNT AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER AS C
           ON A.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
  WHERE (C.FIRST_NM = 'ADAM' OR c.First_NM is null)
```

but c.First_NM must not be nullable or you can't distinguish between the null on the join vs the null on the record.

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ for help on joins.

ORDER of the tables matter...

- If you want all customers and only those accounts which match a
  customer then use a `RIGHT JOIN` as you have listed.
- If you want all accounts and only those customers having a related account, then use a `LEFT JOIN`
- If you want all accounts and all customers use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`
- If you only want customers with accounts use an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

This query will return nulls for the values that are not in Account table and all the records from the Customer table

```
SELECT *
FROM   ACCOUNT AS A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER AS C
       ON A.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
```

This query will return nulls for the values that are not in Customer table and all the records from the Account table

```
SELECT *
FROM   ACCOUNT AS A
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER AS C
       ON A.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
```

This query will not return rows that do not have equivalents in customer table so only rows from accounts that have customers.

```
SELECT *
FROM   ACCOUNT AS A
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS C
       ON A.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
```

Comment: and `WHERE  C.FIRST_NM = 'ADAM'` turns the `LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER AS C` into an inner join

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that you have a match on every key.

If there are no key mismatches, a `RIGHT JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and `INNER JOIN` should all return the same data.

So what you're seeing is that for every customer named `'ADAM'` in `CUSTOMER`, there is a corresponding entry in `ACCOUNT`.